# Table not always horizontally centered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to insert a table in a page by following the code of [this page](https://www.uservoice.com/plans/product-management/).

Here is [my JSBin](http://jsbin.com/puvata/8/edit?html,css,output).

The problem is when we enlarge the output window, the table moves to the left rather than keeping in the center:

[image]

Does anyone know how to always keep the table in the center horizontally?

Additionally, does anyone know how to control the width each column in CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the **.feature-table**

```
.feature-table {
  color: #818181;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In this example works fine, [example](http://jsbin.com/dovekesoyo/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: I try to move the border of the JSBin output, still the table may move to the left...

Comment: the problem was in the css, in .feature-table, when i modified the margin, works fine for me